# MySQL Convert Numbers to letters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an auto-increment transactionID `type=MEDIUMINT(9)` in my table. I want to also display a unique 4-character (which can grow over time, but 4 for now) alphabetical Redemption Code to my users. What is the best way to derive this alphabetical code from my transactionID, preferably straight from the `SELECT statement`?

Comment: You could create the redemption code on the application side (for example - take the modulus of the ID by 26, convert that into a character from A to Z by converting it to a char and adding 48 to it (look at an ASCII table for why this works), divide by 26, repeat until you have 0 left over) and insert that into the table.

Comment: Or if you know the maximum length of the redemption code you can bake it into SQL side by doing something like `CONCAT(CHAR(49+(id/(25*25*25)%25),CHAR(49+(id/(25*25))%25),CHAR(49+(id/25)%25),CHAR(49+id%25)))`

Comment: is the latter option very expensive?

Comment: I doubt it, it's not doing anything fancy. Its worst sin is being ugly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That mostly depends on what alphabet you want to use.

You may use [TO_BASE64](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_to-base64) to convert it it to base64 encoded string or simply do something like:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(your_number, '0', 'A')
, '1', 'B')
, '2', 'C')
, '3', 'D')
, '4', 'E')
, '5', 'F')
, '6', 'G')
, '7', 'H')
, '8', 'I')
, '9', 'J')
```

if you want custom alphabet.

In case you want something shorter, you can go a slightly harder way:

You use 9-digit decimal (maximum 999999999), which translates to 8 hex digits (0x3B9AC9FF), i.e. 4 bytes. What you can do is divide your number in 4 binary octets, convert them to chars, construct new string and feed it to `TO_BASE64()`:

```
select TO_BASE64(CONCAT(CHAR(FLOOR(your_number/(256*256*256))%256),CHAR(FLOOR(your_number/(256*256))%256),CHAR(FLOOR(your_number/256)%256),CHAR(your_number%256)))
```

Note, that TO_BASE64() function is available only in MySQL 5.6 on-wards.

Now, for those on older versions - we don't want to implement `base64` encoding with our bare hands, don't we? So, lets go the easier way: we have 30 bits in those 9 decimal digits, which would be 30/6=5 characters, if we use 64 continuous character alphabet after CHAR(32), which is space, which we don't want to use:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`enter code here`CHAR(FLOOR(your_number/(64*64*64*64))%64+33),CHAR(FLOOR(your_number/(64*64*64))%64+33),CHAR(FLOOR(your_number/(64*64))%64+33),CHAR(FLOOR(your_number/64)%64+64),CHAR(your_number%64+33))
```

Comment: I got a MySQL ERROR 1305 saying that `FUNCTION <dbname>.TO_BASE64 does not exist`. I googled and made sure I have no spaces between function name and `(` but to no avail.

Comment: @user1258600 Uh. Too bad. Can you upgrade to MySQL 5.6?

Comment: okay it seems like this function was only added in MySQL Version 5.6.1. I am still on 5.5.27. :(

Comment: @user1258600 wait a bit, I'll write a slightly longer code to support older versions.

Comment: @user1258600 Now try this one. Change `33` constant to use different ranges, but don't go higher then 63 - you'll cover CHAR(127), which is not quite comfortable to type on normal keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

I was just looking for something like this and I found a way to do it with the [CONV](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) function.

```
CONV(9+your_number, 10, 36)
```

This converts 1 to A, 2 to B etc.

The way it works is by adding 9 and then converting to base 36, in which 10 is A, 11 is B etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a hash with the value of transaction id.

Like:

```
SELECT MD5(transactionID) FROM `yourtable`;
```

There are several other types of similar functions you can [use](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html).

Comment: thank you for the tip. MD5 seems a bit long for my case. I was hoping to get a 4-character alphabet code if possible. If I substring the first four characters of the hash, can I still guarantee a unique?

Comment: @user1258600, Lesser the character length, more chances of clashes.

Comment: @Starx As I understood, he tries to make a unique code for user to type in. More characters - more errors. In case of 64 bits per character in target alphabet and 9 decimal digits in input number, which translates in 30 binary digits, we can get 30/6=5 characters without ANY chance of clash.

Comment: @DavidJashi, Without any chance of clash? What will happen of 10000th record?

Comment: @Starx Nothing. It's five 6-bit characters, not numbers from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can use `CASE WHEN() END;` and stored procedure

For example:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'USERNAME'@'HOST' STORED PROCEDURE `ConvertNumberToAlphabetic`
BEGIN
SELECT 
(CASE
    WHEN (your_number = '1') THEN 'A'
    WHEN (your_number = '2') THEN 'B'
    WHEN (your_number = '3') THEN 'C'
    WHEN (your_number = '4') THEN 'D'
    WHEN (your_number = '5') THEN 'E'
    WHEN (your_number = '6') THEN 'F'
    WHEN (your_number = '7') THEN 'G'
    WHEN (your_number = '8') THEN 'H'
    WHEN (your_number = '9') THEN 'J'
    WHEN (your_number = '10') THEN 'K'
END) RedeemCode
FROM tblTransaction;
END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(transactionId) FROM 1 FOR 4) AS RedemptionCode
```

This creates a 4 character (easy to change, as you can see) string where the characters are from the MD5 command (and therefore in the range a-z and 0-9).

Comment: @DavidJashi : is it really a requirement? what i understand from the question is; getting unique 4 characters from select for display only.

Comment: @AhsanShan 4 hex chars give you maximum of 65536 possible permutations. OP has 9 digits and that gives you maximum of 1000000000  permutations.